# VBA Forms in custom addin

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create an excel addin which has a button when clicked will display a VBA form. Its quite simple one list box and one command button.

Below is the code in Command button

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
ThisWorkbook.IsAddin = False

On Error GoTo ErrHandler:

KeyAcc = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ComboBox1.Value, Sheet1.Range("A:B"), 2, False)
MsgBox KeyAcc
ThisWorkbook.IsAddin = True
Unload Me

Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
MsgBox ComboBox1.Value & " Not found in the Database"
ThisWorkbook.IsAddin = True
Unload Me

ActiveWorkbook.Save = False
End Sub
```

Code in form load

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim cCount As Integer
ThisWorkbook.IsAddin = False
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Select
For cCount = 1 To 320
    UserForm1.ComboBox1.AddItem Range("A" & cCount).Value
Next
ThisWorkbook.IsAddin = True
ComboBox1.SetFocus
End Sub
```

The problem i face is whenever the user activates this button on the first book ie, after opening a new excel and performs the operation it works, once done when i try to close the blank workbook it asks **do you want to Save your changes to the Addin**

Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Why are you using the lines that set `ThisWorkbook.IsAddin`?

Comment: I had issues with lookup when trying to build the code so i used those lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need all that work just to load your combobox:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

Me.ComboBox1.List = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A320").Value
ComboBox1.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Rory. I changed the userform Activate and removed the ThisWorkbook.IsAddin lines in all the codes. Now it is working as expected.